# XML file generating unwanted data

Tags: python, xml

I have tried writing few things to xml file after reading it from a different xml file, everything works smoothly but there are few unwanted tags coming inside the xml file which i generate as output.

Here is what I have tried

```
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
    from xml.dom.minidom import getDOMImplementation
    from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
    tree = ET.parse('C:\\Users\\ca33.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    impl = getDOMImplementation()
    #print(root)
    header = [root.find('header')]
    for h in header:
        h1=(parseString(ET.tostring(h)).toprettyxml(''))
        #print(h1)
    commands = root.findall(".//records//")
    recs=[c for c in commands if c.find('soc_id')!=None and   c.find('soc_id').text[:9]=='000001051']
    bb=""
    for rec in recs:
        aa=(parseString(ET.tostring(rec)).toprettyxml(''))
        bb=bb+aa
    #print(bb)
    newdoc = impl.createDocument(None, "file"+h1+bb, None)
    newdoc.writexml(open('data.xml', 'w'),'\n'.join([line for line in newdoc.toprettyxml(indent=' '*2).split('\n') if line.strip()]))
```

I get the output data.xml file as.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><?xml version="1.0" ?>
<file<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<header>
<number_of_records>41</number_of_records>
</header>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<record>
<soc_id>00000105139E3B82</soc_id>
</record>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soc_id>00000105139E3640</soc_id>
</record>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<header>


<number_of_records>41</number_of_records>
```

So you can see that many tags of `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` is being generated everywhere and in the last it again starts writing the data from first but leaves a 2 line spacing

Comment: So do you mean that you are getting unwanted <?xml version="1.0" ?> in your output ? ? If so make it clear

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan, that is what is happening every time. Unable to remove it.

Comment: don't you think that there is something looping every time because its generating your <?xml version="1.0" ?> each and every time and prints it for every tag.

Comment: Which tags in the output are the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I understand is that you are **trying to read a xml file at first place and then you are trying to write the same data** into a different file.
In this process you are running into problems

```
   from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
   tree = ET.parse('C:\\Users\\ca33.xml')
   root = tree.getroot()
   for header_ex in root.findall('header'):
       h = [ET.tostring(c) for c in header_ex]
       str_header=str(h)
   for record_ex in root.findall('records'):
       r = [ET.tostring(c) for c in record if c.find('soc_id')!=None and c.find('soc_id').text[:9]=='000001051']
       for rec in r:
           str_rec=str(rec)
   with open("output.xml","w") as f:
       f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII' standalone='yes'?>")
       f.write("<file>"+"<header>"+str_header+"</header>")
       f.close()
```

Since you have not posted any random data, I assume it to be the way you had posted in question.I assume that record is a tag and it has something more or many sub/child tags inside it and that's the reason for me to loop twice over it.

> And also stop using unnecessary imports in your code.

Comment: @user8521874 please can you next time post sample data, it will impact your responses and you will get lot of help.